# BASH - задача получения названия дня недели по заданной дате

Tags: bash, unix, дата, shell, функции

Здравствуйте, знатоки. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какая-то функция в BASH, которая по введенной дате (например 2015-06-07) определит название дня недели?
Пример ввода:
1917-11-07
Вывод:
Wednesday

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться утилитой `date`. Правда с ней есть одна проблема -- опции для ввода даты под Linux и BSD сильно отличаются.

Под Linux:

```
$ date -d 1917-11-07 +%A
```

Под BSD (включая OS X):

```
$ date -jf "%Y-%m-%d" 1917-11-07 +%A
```

Comment: *опции для ввода даты под Linux и BSD сильно отличаются* — https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/coreutils/ . и, да, к программе *linux* пакет программ *gnu/coreutils* не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, в смысле не имеет? Большинство Linux дистрибутивов поставляются с Coreutils по-умолчанию. Да и альтернатив особо нет, busybox разве что.

Comment: *в смысле не имеет?* — пакет программ *gnu/coreutils* имеет к программе *linux* не большее отношение, чем, например, стандартная программа *date* из портов *freebsd*.